# Basic Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

here's my code, brand new to coding trying to get the box "points" to return the sum of pointSum if "Ben" is typed into the box "winner". Just trying to work on some basics with this project. Attempting to make a bracket of sorts

```
<HTLML>
<head>
    <script>
        var pointSum = 0;
        var firstRound = 20;
        var secondRound = 50;
        var thirdRound = 100;
        var fourthRound = 150;
        var fifthRound = 250;
        var finalRound = 300;
        var winnerOne = false;
        var winnerTwo = false;
        var winnerThree = false;
        var winnerFour = false;
        var winnerFive = false;
        var winnerSix = false;

        if (winnerOne = true){
            pointSum+=firstRound
        } else if (winnerTwo = true){
            pointSum+=secondRound
        } else if (winnerThree = true){
            pointSum+=thirdRound        
        } else if (winnerFour = true){
            pointSum+=fourthRound
        } else if (winnerFive = true){
            pointSum+=fifthRound
        } else if (winnerSix = true){
            pointSum+=finalRound
        else 

        function tally() {if document.getElementById('winner') == "Ben" { winnerOne = true;
            }
                    pointSum=document.getElementById("points").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Winner: 
        <input type="text" name="winner" id="winner" size="20">
        Points:
        <input type="text" name="points" id="points" size="20">
        Submit 
        <button type= "button" onclick="tally()">Tally points</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE***** new code, getting better, not returning console errors but still not getting anything in the "points" box upon clicking tally

```
<HTLML>
<head>
    <script>
        var pointSum = 0;
        var firstRound = 20;
        var secondRound = 50;
        var thirdRound = 100;
        var fourthRound = 150;
        var fifthRound = 250;
        var finalRound = 300;
        var winnerOne = false;
        var winnerTwo = false;
        var winnerThree = false;
        var winnerFour = false;
        var winnerFive = false;
        var winnerSix = false;

        function tally() {
            var winner = document.getElementById("winner").value; 
            var firstWinner = "Ben";
            if (winner == firstWinner){ 
                winnerOne == true;
            }
                pointSum = document.getElementById("points").value;     
        }           

        if (winnerOne == true){
            pointSum+=firstRound;
        } else if (winnerTwo){
            pointSum+=secondRound;
        } else if (winnerThree){
            pointSum+=thirdRound;
        } else if (winnerFour){
            pointSum+=fourthRound;
        } else if (winnerFive){
            pointSum+=fifthRound;
        } else if (winnerSix){ 
            pointSum+=finalRound;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Winner: 
        <input type="text" name="winner" id="winner" size="20">
        Points:
        <input type="text" name="points" id="points" size="20">
        Submit 
        <button type= "button" onclick="tally()">Tally points</button>

    </form>
    <div class="updatePoints">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're assigning to all of your `winner` variables. Change `winnerOne = true` to `winnerOne == true` or just `winnerOne`. Repeat for all other `if` conditions you're doing. `=` is for assigning values, `==` and `===` is for comparing values. Also, open your console (hit F12). You've got some syntax errors in your `tally` function. Finally, the value is getting summed immediately. You should put all of your summing code inside of your `tally` function.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few mistakes, lets change it a little bit!

First, you need to access 'value' atribbute of your winner element in your if statement, and surround all the statement in parenthesis

```
function tally() {
    if (document.getElementById('winner').value == "Ben"){
        winnerOne = true;
    }
    pointSum = document.getElementById("points").value;
}
```

Second, you use '==' to make comparison, you are using '=', it means that you are assign true to variables, and you're forgetting to put ';' at the end of lines!  change this part:

```
if (winnerOne == true){
     pointSum+=firstRound;
}
```

put all of your if/else like the example above!

Hint: when you are using if statement you can use like this:

```
if (winnerOne){ //you can omit == true, because if winnerOne is true, it will enter ind the if statement
     //will enter here if winnerOne is true
}

if (!winnerOne){ //you can omit == false, because if winnerOne is not true, it will enter ind the if statement
     //will enter here if winnerOne is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have a left over `else` at the end of your `if` check which is invalid. You need to end the last `else if` statement with the `};`.

Are you trying to out put the text somewhere? I don't see any code that is handling this - you may want to add some HTML that will update like so:

```
<div class="updatePoints">
  // leave empty 
</div>
```

Then within your JavaScript you can always add some code to update the `.updatePoints`

```
var points = document.getElementByClass('updatePoints');
points.innerHTML = pointSum.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have add some lines in your code and modify it with some comments. Can try at https://jsfiddle.net/8fhwg6ou/. Hope can help.

```
<HTLML>
<head>
    <script>
        var pointSum = 0;
        var firstRound = 20;
        var secondRound = 50;
        var thirdRound = 100;
        var fourthRound = 150;
        var fifthRound = 250;
        var finalRound = 300;
        var winnerOne = false;
        var winnerTwo = false;
        var winnerThree = false;
        var winnerFour = false;
        var winnerFive = false;
        var winnerSix = false;

        function tally() {
            var winner = document.getElementById("winner").value; 
            var firstWinner = "Ben";
            if (winner == firstWinner){ 
                winnerOne = true; // Use only one = symbol to assign value, not ==
                pointSum = Number(document.getElementById("points").value); // moved from outside and convert to number

                // This code will update point in Points box
                document.getElementById("points").value = tally_pointsum(pointSum);

                // The codes below will add the text in div, just remove the + sign if you don't like
                document.getElementById("updatePoints").innerHTML += (tally_pointsum(pointSum) - pointSum) + " points added<br />";
            }
        }

        // Wrap codes below become a function, lets call it tally_pointsum:
        function tally_pointsum(pointSum) {
            if (winnerOne == true){
                pointSum+=firstRound;
            } else if (winnerTwo){
                pointSum+=secondRound;
            } else if (winnerThree){
                pointSum+=thirdRound;
            } else if (winnerFour){
                pointSum+=fourthRound;
            } else if (winnerFive){
                pointSum+=fifthRound;
            } else if (winnerSix){ 
                pointSum+=finalRound;
            }
            return pointSum; //return the sum to caller
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Winner: 
    <input type="text" name="winner" id="winner" size="20">
    Points:
    <input type="text" name="points" id="points" size="20">
    Submit 
    <button type= "button" onclick="tally()">Tally points</button>

</form>
<!-- change class="updatePoints" to id="updatePoints" for document.getElementById("updatePoints") -->
<div id="updatePoints">
</div>
```

Happy coding.